# lifetime of InstancePerDependency with constructor injection Autofac

Tags: c#, autofac

I am pretty new to the concept of dependency lifetime. I have read the documentation about [different lifetime types](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/lifetime/instance-scope.html).

For the InstancePerDependency, the default one. The page talks about resolving in a lifetimescope so the container will dispose it properly. I can understand this.

But what about when Autofac automatically inject dependency through the constructor. Does the container still hold a reference when a web request completed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This documentation](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/lifetime/disposal.html) helps.

> Note that with Autofac integration libraries standard unit-of-work
>   lifetime scopes will be created and disposed for you automatically.
>   For example, in Autofac’s ASP.NET MVC integration, a lifetime scope
>   will be created for you at the beginning of a web request and all
>   components will generally be resolved from there. At the end of the
>   web request, the scope will automatically be disposed - no additional
>   scope creation is required on your part. If you are using one of the
>   integration libraries, you should be aware of what
>   automatically-created scopes are available for you.

In other words, if Autofac is creating your controllers to handle web requests (which it must be if it's injecting dependencies), then dependencies will be resolved using the scopes created for each controller and disposed when the web request ends.

Comment: Yup. This notion of holding a reference to be disposed is why you shouldn't resolve from the container directly.

Comment: So in this case, IntancePerDependency is effectively the same as InstancePerRequest?

Comment: That's how I understood it.